# Bar's width with categorical axes when using a for-loop

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, figure

I have an issue with plotly, I tried to created a bar chart with categorical axes but the width of the bars decreases greatly when several categories are displayed.

Code :

```
ar = np.array([[0.88, 0.55,0.66,0.87,0.88,0.45,0.56,0.54,0.29,0.45,0.58,0.78], [0.56, 0.59,0.48,0.55,0.45,0.74,0.54,0.56,0.89,0.45,0.56,0.87]])
df = pd.DataFrame(ar, index = ['fight1', 'fight2'], 
                  columns = ['Str. Acc. R1','Str. Acc. R2','Str. Acc. R3',
                             'Str. Acc. opp R1','Str. Acc. opp R2','Str. Acc. opp R3',
                             'TD. Acc. R1', 'TD. Acc. R2','TD. Acc. R3',
                             'TD. Acc. opp R1','TD. Acc. opp R2','TD. Acc. opp R3'])

fig = go.Figure()

dico_SLSA={"Str. Acc." : [col for col in df.columns if "Str." in col],
           "TD. Acc.": [col for col in df.columns if "TD." in col]}

stat = ["Str. Acc."]
##stat = ["Str. Acc.", "TD. Acc."]

for item in stat:
    
    axesx = [["R"+str(i) for i in range(1,4)],[item]*3]
    
    selected_cols = dico_SLSA.get(item)
    selected_cols1 = [col for col in selected_cols if "opp" not in col]
    selected_cols2 = [col for col in selected_cols if "opp" in col]

    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = axesx,
                         y = df[selected_cols1].values.tolist()[0],
                         name = item))

    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = axesx,
                         y = df[selected_cols2].values.tolist()[0],
                         name = item+"_Opp"))



fig.show()
```

With stat=["Str. Acc."] the thickness of the bars is correct but if we select stat=["Str. Acc.","TD. Acc."] the thickness of the bars decreases greatly.

1 category:

[Display with 1 category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OBTU.png)

2 categories:

[Display with 2 categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/couZy.png)

Desire display :

[Desire display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQBY6.png)

I need to keep the for loop because I use this chart with dash and there is a dropdown menu to select data in stat.

Comment: Not sure but try this `fig.update_traces(width=width)`. check this [link](https://community.plotly.com/t/bar-width-using-plotly-express/47580).

Comment: Thanks for your comment unfortunately modify the width does not work properly, the bars overlap.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution, we must add offsetgroup to the trace to solve the problem. as follows :

```
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = axesx,
                     y = df[selected_cols1].values.tolist()[0],
                     name = item,
                     offsetgroup = 0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = axesx,
                     y = df[selected_cols2].values.tolist()[0],
                     name = item+"_Opp",
                     offsetgroup = 1))
```

have a good day !